# Windows Outlook alternative for GIF

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Windows outlook does not support GIFs for HTML emails.

Is there a snippet of code that will target windows outlook only?

Would the below work?

```
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Your Outlook-specific CSS goes here. */
    </style>
 <![endif]-->
```